# Select query where in with partial match

Tags: sql, arrays, sql-server, select

I would like to select all rows from `[Column]` that have within their string the words in a list as so:

```
select [Column]
from [db]
where [Column] like '%some%' or 
      [Column] like '%word%' or
      [Column] like '%and%' or
      [Column] like '%another%'
```

However, as I have a long list of words, I do not want to repeat the `or [Column] like '%%'`. Is there a better way to write this? I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Hi please provide your list and this format

Comment: The `or` is probably the best way to do this, unless you have a full text index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a temporary or variable table and move the `WHERE` to the `JOIN`.

```
DECLARE @PartialMatches TABLE (PartialMatch VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @PartialMatches (PartialMatch)
VALUES ('some'),('word'),('and'),('another')

select 
    D.[Column]
from 
    [db] AS D 
    INNER JOIN @PartialMatches AS P ON D.[Column] LIKE '%' + P.PartialMatch + '%'
```

You can opt to include the like special characters (`%`) on the table or outside. Having them on the table gives more flexibility, you can put `some%` and `%word`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

This one  (match list or not match list) works for me...

```
declare @matchs table ( match varchar(50));
declare @notmatchs table ( notmatch varchar(50));
insert into @matchs (match) values ('%matchfield1%');
insert into @notmatchs (notmatch) values ('%nomatch1'), ('nomatch2%');

select e.* 
from mytable e
where not exists (select top 1 1 from @notmatchs nm where e.ObjectName like nm.notmatch)
and exists (select top 1 1 from @matchs m where e.ObjectName like m.match)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can write your query in below format.

```
select [Column]
from [db]
where [Column] like '%[some-word-and-another]%'
```

Comment: this will not give the same output as the OP is expecting.

Comment: It will not provide the desired output

Comment: yes, this is not correct, it just gives me everything where is not null or blank

Comment: Yes, I have to check my answer and it returns all the row which matches like condition text